# Tribes outside humanity

Tags: human-evolution, psychology, evolutionary-game-theory

All humans are a group with common ancestry but some humans distinct themselves into sub-groups by "distinctive ancestry" and tend to ask other humans "where are you originally from" as to get a satisfying answer about the other side's "distinctive ancestry".
Asking for a precise meaning of this vague question might bring different "exact" versions such as "where were you born?" (some people were born in a ship or an airplane) or "What is your country"? (some people don't affiliate themselves with any country / "stateless") but in the end it generally boils down to "distinctive ancestry".

Is this tendency of many humans to classify other humans into these groups of two or more families with a "distinctive ancestry" (but not by the general group of humanity and not by nuclear family) exist in **animals** (of course, not by asking "where are you originally from" but with much more simple or "primitive" ways of communication)**?**

Do cows/lizards/sheep/squirrels/cats, etc. have a similar classification mechanism?

Comment: Do you mean as wolves do?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. As written essentially any animal with even the most rudimentary social structure (e.g. anything that forms pair bonds for a breeding season) would fit your criteria. Questions on this site are expected to be focused, clear, and demonstrate evidence of prior research (see [tour], [ask], and other [help] for details). In addition, questions that would seem trivial to biology professionals (such as this) are considered ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) — please read the rules for such questions and [edit] or delete your question accordingly.

Comment: Question broadly edited.

Comment: Any of the ungulates, felidae, canids, most schooling fish and social insects still fit the description as I read it.

Comment: @bob1 I know that wolves and birds pack themselves into groups / migrate but I don't know if this must be based on some "middleground ancestry".

Comment: Also, human "tribes" are often not about shared ancestry, but shared beliefs: religion, fans of sports teams, being a supporter of a certain former US President...

Comment: @jamesqf 100% but these are not "at minimum" or at least don't bring a question such as "where are you originally from".

Comment: @al-harumi-jidan - but to the best of our knowledge neither do animals, other than recognizing a "foreigner" by scent or sight, AFAIK most animals don't have the mental abilities to think more than "us" and "not us"

Comment: @al-harumi-jidan: Because "Where are you originally from?" is not usually relevant to those kinds of tribes.

Comment: It seems like your underlying question may be more psychological/social than biological. If you want to know why some people seem obsessed with labelling  people who don't look like them that really doesn't belong on this site. To make this a biological question, you probably need to find a word that doesn't carry the connotations that "tribe" has. For example, are you interested in the question if you replace tribe with something like extended family group? If you are then do some reading based on the multiple hints above and rewrite accordingly. If not please delete it.

Comment: @tyersome My question **is** about biology; I have described a phenomenon common between humans and want to know if there is anything near to it with animals. I think you would need to excuse me from not knowing which term to use instead tribe (which is obviously the nearest thing I could come with). Non registered users can't delete questions and I would not have deleted the question even if could !

Comment: Historically distinct human ancestry was to a large extent due to limited mobility (although also some assortative mating) - this has been changing obly in the last few decades, and mostly in developed countries.

Comment: Your problem is questions like "were were you born?" require adaptations and concepts that to do not appear outside humans in extant animals. The very idea of a question is a human thing. you may however be interested in the tribal behavior of chimpanzees. https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/glowacki/files/wrangham_glowacki_2012_warfare_hunter_gatherers.pdf